# GParted detects 3 partitions instead of 1?

Tags: linux, windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning, gparted

So, I want to use my 2nd HDD for Arch Linux and as storage for my Windows 10 installation. My 2nd HDD only has 1 partition on it (as seen by Windows 10's disk management utility) and that's where all my files are. I wanted to use GParted to chop off the beginning and use it for Linux, but upon booting up my live USB, this is what I saw:
[image: What is this even?]
Soo, it looks like I have a tiny partition with the label that Windows uses for the only partition, and then a normal one, an unknown one, and 1MiB of unallocated space?
Also, I can't seem to resize these, since there are the yellow triangles (unable to read the contents of this file system)...
My 1st HDD (okay, it's an SSD but it doesn't matter rn.) seems to work ok here tho..
I tried to use the terminal to find out what's happening and well... have a look!

```
user@debian:/$ cd mnt/
user@debian:/mnt$ ls /dev/sdb*
/dev/sdb  /dev/sdb1
user@debian:/mnt$ sudo mkdir sdb1
user@debian:/mnt$ sudo ntfs-3g /dev/sdb1 /mnt/sdb1/
user@debian:/mnt$ cd sdb1/
```

And suprisingly, sdb1 had all the files from the partition Windows 10 sees (1tb), and there were no sdb2, or sdb3 in /dev...
Can someone help me fix it and finally resize my partition?
(I tried: chkdsk /f (on the right drive,ofc.), but no luck)
Reply to comment 'cause of long text:

```
user@debian:~$ sudo fdisk -t dos -l /dev/sdb
Disk /dev/sdb: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD10JPVX-60J
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x778bafcd

Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1               63       2047       1985 992.5K 42 SFS
/dev/sdb2  *          2048 1953519615 1953517568 931.5G 42 SFS
/dev/sdb3       1953519616 1953523119       3504   1.7M 42 SFS

Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
user@debian:~$ sudo fdisk -t gpt -l /dev/sdb
Disk /dev/sdb: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD10JPVX-60J
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

Comment: Can you show `fdisk -t dos -l /dev/sdb` and `fdisk -t gpt -l /dev/sdb`?

Comment: @grawity ok,just a few minutes 'till I reboot and do it

Comment: @grawity it seems to detect 3 partitions as well.. I included the GPT command as well, but I don't think it has anything interesting since it's in MBR format. It's too long, but I added it in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it!
Turns out the disk was "Dynamic" as Windows said, but after converting it back to basic, it works perfectly now!